# Wireless Mesh or just renaming accesspoint

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wds

I'm a newbie for these kind of things so forgive me if I say something wrong :)
suppose we have 3 access-points and they all have physical cable back to server, I want to have 1 expanded network (SSID="MyWirelesssNet"). so what is the difference between using full mesh WDS or just rename all of the APs to "MyWirelesssNet". what is the best method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to set all of them with the same SSID, and dont forget to put them in different channels (or set them to "auto channel" if they support that) to avoid interferences. When client devices will connect, they will choose the best access point themselves.

Mesh/WDS is for the case when you don't have ethernet cables to the server, so the access points uses WIFI to another wire-connected access point to reach the server. It's better to avoid it when possible because it has severe impact on WIFI performance.

Comment: month a go i try to set all of APs with the same SSID but some of smart phones when take place in the edge of  WIFI coverage area, they constantly switch between APs so the internet connection become unavailable. is there any solution for that?

Comment: tnx for your answer by the way

Comment: I think only reliable solution is to add more APs on the areas where coverage is weak.